# Markdown code blocks render in a very weird nested way

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I checked other blogs that use the `Jekyll-guthub-pages` system and code blocks display properly on their rendered site but on mine, it shows up as a double-nested code block with empty vertical & horizontal scroll bars.

This is what shows up when I write the following markdown

````
```cs
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver("./")
```
````

[image: weird nested code blocks]

The same thing happens if I try to use only the `github-style` indentation except I don't get any colouration.

Is there a configuration setting to alter? How can I fix it?

I found that using the following displays a somewhat proper code block, except that it won't have any colouration...

```
<pre>
  <code class="csharp">  
// code here
  </code>
</pre>
```

Comment: that's probably caused by some CSS.. use your browser's developer tools to inspect and change your CSS accordingly.

Comment: @wndrr it depends which theme you are using, try editing your CSS using dev tools.